# C size_t not printing in printf

Tags: c, strlen, size-t

I have two strings, both of which are equal, and I get their lengths like this

```
size_t len = strlen(s1);
size_t len2 = strlen(s2);
```

I need to know what those are equal to, since the strings will not always be equal, so I tried printing out both values like this

```
printf("len1: %zu len2: %zu", len, len2);
```

but, this prints nothing. If I put this

```
printf("%s %s\n", s1, s2);
```

in the line above it, it prints out `test string test string`, which tells me that neither string is `NULL`. What is causing the string lengths to not print?

Comment: `strlen(s1);` doesn't give size but returns length, how do you declares s1, s2 ?

Comment: I meant length, my bad.

Comment: You have `\n` at the end of the format specifier on your second example but not the first.  What happens if you add `\n` to the first?  Perhaps the line is being buffered?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `strlen` returns type `size_t`

Comment: Some platforms have problems with `%zu`. Try printing it using `%lu`.

Comment: @cdhowie That just fixed it, but I've used printf without putting `\n` at the end before, how did that make a difference?

Comment: @ChrisLoonam if your compiler doesn;t support (e.g. microsoft)  then use `%lu`

Comment: @ChrisLoonam It would depend on what the program does following the printf() call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first `printf` is missing a `\n`, so the output is getting buffered (and not flushed to the console). Either add a newline to the string, or use `fflush`.